# If Toy Bonnie is in the Right Vent, is it possible put the mask on fast enough after opening and closing the monitor?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-2

I'm playing Five Night's at Freddy's 2 (FNaF 2), I'm on night 4, and keep getting murdered by Toy Bonnie, who lurks in the vents when I pull up the monitor. I've tried getting the Freddy Mask in time but can't do it. Is it possible to pull up the mask after accedentally pulling up the monitor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, there is. To have this happen another animatronic has to come into the room (Golden Freddy, Old Bonnie, etc.).

For Example: Let's say that Toy Bonnie was about to attack you as you put the monitor up. However, Toy Freddy comes into the room. He would force Toy Bonnie to stop attacking you and effectively save your life (never thought I'd be saying this, but thank you, Toy Freddy!)

Basically, yes, you can avoid Toy Bonnie, but you would have to have another animatronic attack you at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You only have 15 seconds, so you have to move fast. Trust me, it's hard as a rock. You have to move a nano-second faster than the animatronic. Foxy will try to attack you at the same time. Have fun with that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't check the cameras, only wind up the music box, and every time you put down the camera, put your mask on quickly.  Don't check the cameras, It's a waste of time. Use this technique during nights 3-7. Use the cameras for puppet, though.